# How can I use " inside expect send command with variable

Tags: bash, expect

I have used the /usr/bin/expect to SSH into my other system and execute some commands using send.

Here is command that need to send where 5100097654311 is variable that need to be manual input: `SHOW EPC EXAPN:APNNAME="4gdata",IMSI="5100097654311"`

Here is the script:

```
read -p "Enter IMSI Number : " userimsi
usermnc=${userimsi:0:5}
echo ${usermnc}
/usr/bin/expect SHOW_bindingxGW.ttxt 172.28.24.37 $userimsi $usermnc  > /result/xGWbinding.txt
sleep 10
inside SHOW_bindingxGW.ttxt
===========
set saddress [lrange $argv 0 0]
set userimsi [lrange $argv 1 1]
set usermnc [lrange $argv 2 2]
expect ">"
send 'SHOW MME EXAPN:APNNAME=\"smartfren4g\",IMSI=\"$userimsi\"'
send "\r"
expect ">"
send "logout\r"
```

i use escape character \ the result as bellow:

```
Enter IMSI Number : 5442313123
54423
usage: send [args] string
    while executing
"send 'SHOW MME EXAPN:APNNAME=\"smartfren4g\",IMSI=\"$userimsi\"'"
    (file "/home/lte/budi/mme/SHOW_bindingxGW.ttxt" line 8)
```

i suspect because I use variable in command $userimsi.

is there any solution where, I can sent "" and variable under expect command ?

Thanks.

Comment: imho this is really about Tcl rather than bash - fwiw I think you just need to change the outer quotes from single `'` to double `"`. See for example [Expect script - quotes needed with send string conflict with quotes required by expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39239767/4440445)

Comment: You don't need to escape the `"` inside the `'`. But can you show us what output you want to have? You could do `send 'SHOW MME EXAPN:APNNAME="smartfren4g",IMSI="$userimsi"'` but that would not expand the value of `$userimsi`. Is that what you want? Or do you want the value expanded (so `send "SHOW MME EXAPN:APNNAME=\"smartfren4g\",IMSI=\"$userimsi\""`)?

Comment: Hi terdon, i want second option. and I try your solution. it's work well. thanks a lot. this command work well for me.send "SHOW MME EXAPN:APNNAME=\"smartfren4g\",IMSI=\"$userimsi\"\r"

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value of the variable to be expanded, you need to use `"`, so you then need to escape any other, internal `"`:

```
send "SHOW MME EXAPN:APNNAME=\"smartfren4g\",IMSI=\"$userimsi\""
```